# Error loading Private Keys in .net core on remote machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .net core web API project to process JWT tokens which uses the Eliptic Curve ES256 (secp256r1) certificates.

The certificates are cipher encrypted into a database.

I can retrieve and verify incoming tokens however I am having an issue while trying to retrieve the private key for signing new tokens.

The function I am using is:

```
private static ECDsa LoadPrivateKey(string privateKey)
{
    var ecDsaCng = new ECDsaCng(CngKey.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey), CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob));

    ecDsaCng.HashAlgorithm = CngAlgorithm.ECDsaP256;

    return ecDsaCng;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that while this works fine on my local development machine, when I deploy it to the test server it fails with the message

> An internal error occurred

I enables logging and can confirm the value retrieved is same in both the remote server as well as my development machine.

How to solve this?

Comment: what's the exception and stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

So I finally managed to understand what the issue is here.
When I deployed it to the test server running under IIS, it seems that the user under which the APP Pool is running was not a local administrator on the test box.

it seems that to create a private key on the machine we need the user (in this case the APP Pool) to be a local administrator

I refered to this URL while trying to debug this and it did point me in the right direction:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2012/08/17/cngkey-import-throws-an-exception-saying-an-internal-error-occurred-when-importing-a-key-blob-under-a-non-admin-user-from-a-wcf-web-service/